# Stripe - Payout the sellers with custom amounts (On demand)

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, e-commerce, payment-gateway

### The situation

In my e-commerce project, I'm using stripe card element to catch payments from customers to the platform's Stripe account. After my Laravel application listens to the webbook of a successful payment that is fired by Stripe, the app then fires a job to add credit on the seller's platform account. **This part works perfectly fine**.

### The question

Is there a way to add some sort of a button in the seller's profile on the platform that allows the seller to receive exactly the amount that is on their account on the platform?

Let's say he has $100 credit on the platform, after clicking 'pay me' button, the seller will get this $100 paid out from the platform's stripe account to his bank account.

#### I have accomplished until now:

1- A visitor can add item to cart and checkout.

2- Uses stripe card element to take the payment.

3- When payment is successful, the amount goes to the platform's stripe account.

4- The application listens to successful payment webhook and adds credit to the seller's account on the platform (As simple as having a column on the database for each seller with the default of 0 and it increases upon each successful customer payment).

#### Thoughts

What do you think about this? https://stripe.com/docs/connect/add-and-pay-out-guide

I'm thinking of using this technique since I'm doing everything manual. I believe I can skip the part where I top-up my Stripe account (Since it should be having credit by default from the successful payment).

So here is what I think:

0- A customer makes a successful payment towards some products and the application catches Stripe webhooks and fires a job to add credit to the seller's platform account.

1- The seller receives a notification that he has credit on the platform's account.

2-  The seller then can click on a button that takes him to a route where I redirect him to create (stripe express account)[https://stripe.com/docs/connect/add-and-pay-out-guide?integration=with-code#with-code-create-account-link]

3- After the seller gets redirected to the platform again and I catch the webhook that account has been created, The seller then will be redirected to receive the determined amount by my platform. https://stripe.com/docs/connect/add-and-pay-out-guide?integration=with-code#with-code-pay-out-to-user

Answer (score 1):

You can ask your sellers to register an express account when they onboard your platform, so that your sellers can submit all necessary documentation for account verification and make their accounts payout enabled.

When your customer is about to make a payment, you should create a [destination charge](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges) so that Stripe can automatically transfer the funds from platform to a connected account, you can also opt to charge an application fee from this transaction if you wish.

Stripe will automatically perform payouts based on the account's payout [schedule](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update#update_account-settings-payouts-schedule-interval) , if you prefer to do it manually, change the schedule's [interval](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/update#update_account-settings-payouts-schedule-interval) to `manual` . Visit this [page](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/manual-payouts) to learn more about manual payouts.